# Elasticsearch の費用見積もりについて

Tags: bluemix, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch の費用見積もりは、Compose 社のサイトの説明どおり、最初の2GBが$45/月、以後1GBごとに$18/月と、データ量だけで決まるという理解で正しいでしょうか。
DBサーバーのスペックは、サーバー側で「適宜設定」であり、指定はできないということになりますでしょうか。

またWebのcalculator では100GBまでしか計算できませんが、あとは単純に$18/GB・月で追加されていくということでしょうか。